# Microalbuminuria in inflammation of urinary tract

Tags: human-biology, physiology, pathology, renal-physiology

> Albumin is excreted into urine (albuminuria) in nephrotic syndrome and in certain inflammatory conditions of urinary tract.[$^1$](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=Bd9XAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA185&lpg=PA185&dq=Albumin%20is%20excreted%20into%20urine%20(albuminuria)%20in%20nephrotic%20syndrome%20and%20in%20certain%20inflammatory%20conditions%20of%20urinary%20tract.&source=bl&ots=_2n1ZSU6MW&sig=1fhdVa8hFlzeiWEitP7kbes74Dg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibm6e-w5fVAhUGkpQKHf31AF8Q6AEINjAD#v=onepage&q=Albumin%20is%20excreted%20into%20urine%20(albuminuria)%20in%20nephrotic%20syndrome%20and%20in%20certain%20inflammatory%20conditions%20of%20urinary%20tract.&f=false)

How is inflammation in urinary tract related to increase in albumin excretion? I know that microalbuminuria will result when albumin filtered is greater than its absorption( which takes place in nephron, not related to urinary tract).

---

My attempt : After some research I found [this,](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3005216/) which states cause of microalbuminuria in children may be causing infection in glomerulus, leading to increased permeability of glomerular basement membrane.

So, will it be correct to say that UT inflammation is not causing directly microalbuminuria?

Comment: UT infection in glomerulus causes inflammation of Glomerulus which causes increased permeability of glomerulus that directly cause increased filtration  of albumin. So, more is excreted as well.

Comment: in a nut shell, its indirect effect?

Comment: Direct effect.  Inflammation caused increased permeability which itself means protein filterablity.

Comment: inflammation is in ut which is not a place where filtration takes place. re read my question.